# Is calling async code from a callback API safe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, udp, datagram

I'm using the callback-based `dgram` modules to build a UDP server.

I'm using the async mysql2/promise API, to make the DB code easier to read.

Currently, I use:

```
const dgram = require('dgram');
const mysql2 = require('mysql2/promise');

async function main() 
    const db = await mysql2.createConnection({
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 3306,
        ...
    });

    async function insert_into_db(msg, rinfo) {
        var result = await db.execute('INSERT INTO ...
        ...
    }

    ...

    server.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
        insert_into_db(msg, rinfo).catch(err => { console.error(err); });
    }

    server.bind(41234);
}

main().catch(err => { console.error(err); process.exit(1); });
```

Is this the best way to call async code form callback code?  (It's working.)

Will I face any performance issues which I wouldn't face if I switched to `mysql2's` callback API?

Comment: Callbacks do not work very well with promises in the same code, the main issues are at error handling as it's super easy to miss to handle and error from a callback in a try catch block on an async module. I highly suggest to promisify the api of the callback module, using either require('util').promisity or bluebird.promisify.

Comment: _Is this the best way to call async code form callback code? (It's working.)_

-  I don't' see any problem in your code ( I'm mysql2 author ). Single mysql connection requires waiting for query to complete before sending another one but the driver handles that for you

Comment: @AndreySidorov Thanks for writing mysql2, and for your comment.